# SQLiteConstraintException: notes.date may not be NULL (code 19)

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating a notes functionality in my app and used the google notes tutorial for it.
It works perfect but on all devices except one where I get `SQLiteConstraintException: notes.date may not be NULL (code 19)`.

Here's the log:

```
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434): Error inserting body=testbody
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):  title=testtitle
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: notes.date may not be NULL (code 19)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:779)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at com.fleank.skybuddy.NotesDbAdapter.createNote(NotesDbAdapter.java:125)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at com.fleank.skybuddy.NoteEdit.saveState(NoteEdit.java:129)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at com.fleank.skybuddy.NoteEdit.onPause(NoteEdit.java:102)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5224)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1232)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3197)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3166)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3144)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
10-29 16:01:39.392: E/SQLiteDatabase(7434):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The strange thingy is that I don't have any date value defined. As you can see I just have title and body. Am I missing any basic SQL knowledge?
I have to admit that I'm totally lost with this issue :-(

My saveState() Method:

```
 private void saveState() {
    String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    String body = mBodyText.getText().toString();

    if (title.equals("") && body.equals("")) {
        if (note != null) {
            note.close();
            note = null;
        }
        if (mRowId != null) {
            mDbHelper.deleteNote(mRowId);
        }
    }

    else {
        if (mRowId == null) {
            long id = mDbHelper.createNote(title, body); //This is row 129
            if (id > 0) {
                mRowId = id;
            }
        } else {
            mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, title, body);
        }
    }
```

...and the createNote() Method from NotesDBAdapter:

```
    public long createNote(String title, String body) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues); //This is row 125
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

**Update: Added the complete NotesDbAdapter with the creation** (Taken from google notes tutorial and slightly adjusted to my needs):

```
public class NotesDbAdapter {

public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

private static final String TAG = "NotesDbAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

/**
 * Database creation sql statement
 */
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "title text not null, body text not null);";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

/**
 * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
 * opened/created
 * 
 * @param ctx the Context within which to work
 */
public NotesDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

/**
 * Open the notes database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
 * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
 * signal the failure
 * 
 * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
 *         initialization call)
 * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
 */
public NotesDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}


/**
 * Create a new note using the title and body provided. If the note is
 * successfully created return the new rowId for that note, otherwise return
 * a -1 to indicate failure.
 * 
 * @param title the title of the note
 * @param body the body of the note
 * @return rowId or -1 if failed
 */
public long createNote(String title, String body) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

/**
 * Delete the note with the given rowId
 * 
 * @param rowId id of note to delete
 * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
 */
public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

    return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

/**
 * Return a Cursor over the list of all notes in the database
 * 
 * @return Cursor over all notes
 */
public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

/**
 * Return a Cursor positioned at the note that matches the given rowId
 * 
 * @param rowId id of note to retrieve
 * @return Cursor positioned to matching note, if found
 * @throws SQLException if note could not be found/retrieved
 */
public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

    Cursor mCursor =

        mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

/**
 * Update the note using the details provided. The note to be updated is
 * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title and body
 * values passed in
 * 
 * @param rowId id of note to update
 * @param title value to set note title to
 * @param body value to set note body to
 * @return true if the note was successfully updated, false otherwise
 */
public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String title, String body) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    args.put(KEY_BODY, body);

    return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Your table has a `date` column with `not null` and since you're not giving the column a value, it defaults to null. Post your schema (the `CREATE TABLE` and so on).

Comment: Have you edited the schema without updating `DATABASE_VERSION` / removing the old database file?

Comment: @laalto You're right! It seems I had an older version on this particular device. Uninstalling and reinstalling fixed the issue. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error suggests you have a column 'date' that has a not null constraint.

As the DATABASE_CREATE doesn't mention 'date', I can only assume that it used to and then you changed it without updating the DATABASE_VERSION. Try increasing that as it should then call onUpgrade which will drop the DB to allow you to create the new version without the 'date' column

Comment: You're right, same as laalto wrote. It was my silly mistake that I had changed the DB w/o uninstalling it first so there was still date in it. Thanks for the hint and sorry for my stupid issue